# network vs DHCP server

Tags: networking

Relatively simple home network where a FiOS modem/router provides DHCP IP addresses:

FiOS Router has its own SSIDs, an Asus WiFI Router connected by ethernet (to FiOS Router) also has it's own SSIDs, does not provide DHCP - all addresses are given out by FiOS router.  Both FiOS and Asus also have ethernet connected devices.

Would all devices connected via WiFi or ethernet to either the FiOS or Asus router be considered on the same network given all addresses are given out by FiOS router in the 192.168.0.xxx range?

Comment: Yes.  Everything is in the same subnet.

Comment: @ivanivan wrong. They may use the same subnet addresses, but if the second router isn't configured as an extender, the two networks will be completely separate.

Comment: It depends on how the Asus Wifi Router is configured (which is why you get contradicting answers below). Different SSIDs or DHCP presence or absence are not the point, the point is if the Asus router will create a different subnet on its LAN ports, and possibly also do NAT. Many home routers do both by default.

Answer (score 1):

> Would all devices connected via WiFi or ethernet to either the FiOS or
>   Asus router be considered on the same network given all addresses are
>   given out by FiOS router in the 192.168.0.xxx range?

The short answer is Yes.

You describe a scenario where all of your devices are given an IP address by your FiOS router using DHCP. This implies that all devices on your network are on the same logical network, utilizing the same subnet. DHCP does not work across network boundaries without a helper function. Therefore, despite the technical details other commenters have suggested, it appears you have already placed your Asus router in a “bridge” configuration.

Answer (score -1):

No, as the Asus router creates an entirely new network even though it is connected to the main router. You couldn't loop back to the Fios router. If you were just using the ASUS router for ethernet, a better way to do that would be to use a network switch, and if you need wifi, you could use a WiFi range extender, something like this ([amzn.to/2xtuS39](http://amzn.to/2xtuS39)) This is the one I use and it works well.
Hope this helps

Comment: This is wrong, because there is only 1 DHCP server....

Answer (score -2):

> Would all devices connected via WiFi or ethernet to either the FiOS or Asus router be considered on the same network given all addresses are given out by FiOS router in the 192.168.0.xxx range?

**No** is the simple answer. It actually depends on your configuration.
In order for them to be in the same network, the second router (the ASUS one) needs to be configured as a **bridge** in the FiOS router's network, not as **gateway**. Any router by default is configured as a **gateway** - it has its own network and for example the FiOS router won't be able to see the ASUS router's clients (and won't be able to give them IP addresses by DHCP *directly*). Even if both routers have the same private network range - the two networks are not the same one.

In order for the all clients to be in the same network, the second (ASUS) router must be configured as a bridge - just to extend the network and not act as a gateway. That way both routers' clients will be able to ping and connect with each other.

---

There is no problem using a router as a network extender. It actually is better, because you can use one router device as both a physical network extender **and** a WiFi range extender. You just need to configure it properly, and that depends on the firmware of the router (and is also for a whole another question, if you need help).

Comment: Wait wait, "router" and "gateway" are [the same thing](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1812#section-1), and a device acting as a router will always separate two networks, not join them. Did you mean "needs to be configured as a **bridge**"?

Comment: What @Grawity said. You need to configure the ASUS as a bridge so you extend the FiOS network, *not* as a router as that will create a separate network. The simplest is probably to connect the FiOS router to one of the ASUS' switch ports (NOT the WAN port) and disable DHCP on the ASUS.

Comment: Seems like it was my misunderstanding, since on some open-source firmwares the network mode on routers for bridging is actually called "Router". I'll update the answer with the proper term.